# AWS Elastic Beanstalk django app is not accepting AWS SES credentials

Tags: django, amazon-web-services

I am writing a simple Django app to send emails, and I am hosting on AWS' Elastic Beanstalk. Before I hosted on EB, the credentials worked (located in my ~/.aws/credentials). I am getting an AccessDenied error when I try to run the SES sendEmail function. I even put the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and the AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY in the settings.py file. I made sure my keys were correct, my email was verified with AWS, etc.

Comment: Did you check whether the user has IAM access to SES?

Comment: Also, you might want to check if SES is supported in your region. If not, you might have to switch regions for SES.

Comment: @JonSaw I have full credentials. Do I have to link the email to my user? Or does the email have nothing to do with it? I am in us-west-2 so I believe it's supported.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any other solution so I did the following:

client = boto3.client('ses', aws_access_key_id = "my key", aws_secret_access_key = "my secret key")

This solved the credentials problem. Not sure why boto3 couldn't find my credentials.